# Class template and friendship

Tags: c++, templates, friend, class-template

I have this example on class templates and friends:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo;

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Foo<T> const&);

template <typename T>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Foo<T>&);

template <typename T>
class Foo{
private:
    int x = 10;
    friend std::ostream& operator<< <T>(std::ostream&, Foo const&);
    friend std::istream& operator>> <>(std::istream&, Foo&);
};

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Foo<T> const& f){
    return os << f.x;
}

template <typename T>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Foo<T>& f){
    return is >> f.x;
}


int main(){

    Foo<double> fd;
    std::cin >> fd;
    std::cout << fd << '\n';

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

- The wroks fine but I want to know the difference between the insertion operator `<<` friendship type and the extraction operator `>>` friendship type to class `Foo`.
- Does `...operator<< <T>..` that each instantiation of the output operator for the same type used to instantiate `Foo` is its friend? So Is this One-To-One friendship?
- What confuses me is the extraction operator: `operator >> <>(...`: What does this mean? Is this a full specialization?

Answer (score 2):

> The wroks fine but I want to know the difference between the insertion
> operator `<<` friendship type and the extraction operator `>>` friendship
> type to class `Foo`.

They have the same effect here.

> Does `...operator<< <T>..` that each instantiation of the output
> operator for the same type used to instantiate `Foo` is its friend? So
> Is this One-To-One friendship?

Yes. For `Foo<double>`, only `operator<< <double>` and `operator>> <double>` are friends.

> What confuses me is the extraction operator: `operator>> <>(...`: What
> does this mean? Is this a full specialization?

Template argument deduction is performed to determine the type `T` (based on the 2nd function parameter; `Foo` is same as `Foo<T>`), then the friend declaration refers to the instantiation for the deduced `T`. It's just same as specifying template argument `T` as `operator>> <T>(...`.